# how does normalizing vectors go with game programming

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine, normalize

I was unfortunate enough to attend a high school that did not care about preparing students for college, but I'm studying some game programming, and everything programming I get, but I'm taking a Game AI course and we're learning about FSM's and AI movements, and I came across "normalize", looked into it and it kind of makes sense, but how would I use this in game programming? Maybe I just don't understand the concept that well (never really took an algebra class, although I use way higher level mathematics everyday in other programming, however I learn as I go), but I just don't get why I would need to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vectors represent both length and direction. Sometimes it's handy to use a "unit vector" (with length one) for multiplication, because it's easy to control the result's length.

Multiply a one-pound weight by five, and what do you have? A five-pound weight.

Multiply a unit vector by five, and what do you have? A vector pointing five units in that direction.

As a practical example, let's say I'm writing a camera system for a simple game: two cars race against each other on a straight track. The camera should orbit around the player's car while looking in the direction of the opponent.

Since you tagged the question with [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d), I'll offer C# code that would compile in Unity3D. The basic concepts are the same for any use, though.

Let's assume we're given two points:

```
Vector3 playerPos, enemyPos;
```

Some operations we might find useful:

```
//find separation between two points
Vector3 playerToEnemy = enemyPos - playerPos;

//find distance between them
float distance = playerToEnemy.magnitude;

//find direction of separation
Vector3 enemyDirection = playerToEnemy.normalized;
```

Finally, we position the camera:

```
Vector3 camPos = playerPos;    //start at player's position
camPos -= enemyDirection * 10f; //move ten units away from enemy
camPos += Vector3.up * 5f;      //move five units up

Transform tr = Camera.main.transform;    
tr.position = camPos;
tr.LookAt(enemyPos);
```

You may notice that I used one of Unity3D's built-in unit vectors (including `Vector3.up`, `Vector3.right`, and `Vector3.forward`). Every transform object in Unity also has local-space equivalents.

Another use: with vector dot products, you can check if two normalized vectors point in similar directions because the dot product's output will range from -1 (opposite directions) to 0 (perpendicular) to 1 (parallel).

Comment: I wish math came to me as easy as programming does, but thanks man, this example absolutely makes more sense.